# __file__ in Maya not defined(#NameError)

Tags: python, maya

This seems like a questions that get asked a lot but so far I did not have found a working answer.

I am working in Maya 2020 and try to make a script that need to work with some relative and absolute paths.

This is my script:

```
import os

print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep
```

this is the path to my script:
Y:\New folder\my_script.py

When I run:

```
execfile("Y:\New folder\my_script.py")
```

I always get the error:

```
# NameError: name '__file__' is not defined #
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: I don't believe `execfile` creates a module as a normal import does, and because of this lacks items such as `__file__`.

Is there a particular reason you need to use `execfile`? I can more or less guarantee that there are better ways to do what you're needing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `execfile` is a deprecated function in Python 3 and it is better to avoid using it. They suggest to use `exec(open(fn).read())` instead (in fact, that's how it works under the hood). If you look at the suggested replacement, you'll see why the `__file__` is not defined (it is not a file but a text that is interpreted as a Python code).

The usual way to import files in Maya is to place them in a directory that is added to a `PYTHONPATH`. There is a default Maya script directory in your user's Documents. Depending on your platform and Maya version this could be: `C:\Users\<your_user>\Documents\maya\2020\scripts`
Another option is to add your directory to `PATH`. Usually this looks like this:

```py
import sys
MY_SCRIPT_PATH = "/Some/path/with/my/scripts"
if MY_SCRIPT_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(MY_SCRIPT_PATH
```

Then if your script file is named `my_script.py` you can import it:

```py
import my_script
```

And now your `__file__` variable will work as expected.

P.S. If you change your file and want to reload:

```py
reload(my_script)
```